# Window Restore event listener for swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener, windowstate

I have used `WindowStateListener` for listening window maximized event. I am sucessful on that. But when I restore the frame to its original size (the button that appears at the maximized icon when the window is maximized), the buttons get invisible. I think I need to handle the restore event and then repaint those buttons. Here is what I have done so far

```
    frame.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if((e.getNewState() & Frame.ICONIFIED) == Frame.ICONIFIED){

                    }
                    else if ((e.getNewState() & Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) == Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH){
                        System.out.println("Maximized");

                        scaleButtons();
                        maximized = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        maximized = false;
                    }
                }
            });
```

I want to handle jframe restored event. How to do that

Comment: What buttons?  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I just want to handle window resized listener, the restore button which comes after the window is maximized

Comment: *"I just want to handle window resized listener.."*  1) See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) 2) For better help sooner, post an **[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: As an aside, a lot of your [earlier questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3454286/viper?tab=questions) seem to have answers, but no *accepted* answer.  You might want to look into fixing that.